# add open face chinese

Tags: feature-request

I posted a [question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/4150/309) about pineapple OFC and was told that it was not within the scope of the poker stackexchange. I was wondering if we could add Open Face Chinese (OFC) and its pineapple variant POFC to be valid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-face_Chinese_poker

Comment: Could you add links to examples of each game so myself & others can take a look at the games you're asking about, thanks.

Comment: beyond a link to wikipedia? what do you want exactly?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-face_Chinese_poker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked into it more deeply & id suggest that OFC and its variants are On-Topic.

My reasoning being in relation to another game that was suggested, "Pandante", which id suggest is off-topic.

To be a poker variant there are a couple of constraints more important than others that need fulfilling. Those are use of a standardized deck, and use of a common hierarchy of hand rankings. OFC and variants of it have those characteristics.

An argument used with Pandante was that similarities in skill sets (eg. Counting outs, psychology, etc.) were important. I wouldn't call baseball and tennis variants of the same game because they both requires ball striking skills.

I propose reopening the question.

Comment: Thank you a lot for looking into this. I really really wanted to do some research on my own on the subject in order to make a more informed decision, but the past few days were just packed for me, so there was no way I could find some time to do it. Tomorrow (Sunday) I have time, so I promise I will look into it; I will probably come to the same conclusion: it should be on-topic.

Comment: Mate no probs ;) It was worth looking in to. I'll leave it to you to re-open if you come to that decision.

Comment: I reopened the question.